# Hidden field in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, view, field

I have this form in a view in my project. I need to pass the `task_id` to a certain controller, but the log does not seem to be receiving the parameters. I don't know what the problem is.

```
<%= form_for :taskid, :url => {:action=>"index", :controller=>"statistics"}, :html => {:class => "nifty_form", :method => "GET"} do |f| %>
  <%f.hidden_field :task_id, :value => task.id%>
  <td><%= f.submit "اختر مهمة لاظهار احصائياتها منفرده"%></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check the HTML source code as well to see that the value is actually there.

Comment: What is :taskid? It's just a model, not an object. And its attributes are empty. Pass existed object @task from the controller to this form, or use hidden_field_tag

Answer (score 59):

You are missing on `=` after `<%`. The equal sign is needed whenever you want to the result appears on the HTML, so it is used with the field tags methods or render, for instance. You should not use the equal when using a `if`, for example, because this is not what you want to print (well, it can be, but most likely it isn't)

```
<%= form_for :taskid, :url => {:action=>"index", :controller=>"statistics"}, :html => {:class => "nifty_form", :method => "GET"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :task_id, :value => task.id%>
  <td><%= f.submit "اختر مهمة لاظهار احصائياتها منفرده"%></td>
<% end %>
```

However, as @AntonGrigoriev pointed out, you should use a object if you have, like this

```
<%= form_for @task, :url => {:action=>"index", :controller=>"statistics"}, :html => {:class => "nifty_form", :method => "GET"} do |f| %>
```

or you can simply use the [hidden_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :task_id, task.id %>
```

Answer (score -4):

Hi please test with following code to send hidden value in rails, I have tried and worked for one of my application :

`hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})` public
eg:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:field_name,value=@offer_status)%>
```