# How to use hidden field tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have this form, but already have a variable, client_id, that I want to pass to the controller. It looks like I need to use a hidden_field_tag. I tried it but I don't think my syntax is quite right. Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
<%= form_for(@assessment) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :weight %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :weight %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :heartrate %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :heartrate %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bodyfat %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bodyfat %>
  </div>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :client_id, @client.id %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where you are setting @client object? and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, value: @assessment.client_id %>
```

Since, as in your prior question, you are setting @assessment.client_id in your `new` action.

Answer (score 13):

Please refer following links [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002295)  or [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002252)

```
        <%= f.hidden_field :client_id, 1 %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'client_id', '1'  %>
```

Note when you used

```
   <%= f.hidden_field :client_id, 1 %>
```

it change to html

```
<input type="hidden" id="request_client_id" name="request[client_id]" value="1" />
```

and when you used

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'client_id', '1'  %>
```

it change to html

```
   <input id="client_id" name="client_id" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

So, I think here you should use  `<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, @client.id %>`

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, value: @client.id %>
```

Some source:

- https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field
- [Hidden field in rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280341/hidden-field-in-rails-form)
- [How do I use hidden_field in a form_for in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131982/how-do-i-use-hidden-field-in-a-form-for-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3):

`<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, :value => @assessment.client_id %>`

Answer (score 1):

Should the client_id be part of the assessment_params? If so, you can attach it to the form object, i.e. `<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, value: @client.id`.

Otherwise I think your tag should pass through, just outside of the assessment params hash.